# UITableViewController in popOver container

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6

I hope someone can help:

I am using a popover style container for an iPhone app. I am trying to put a UITableViewController into the container - but  keep getting the NSInternalInconsistancyException error - stating that I have not set up the tableviewcontroller with a prototype cell etc - which as far as I can see I have. The TVC I am placing in the container is in the main storyboard but not connected to any other views via segues.

Should I be using seperate nib files for this TVC and TableViewCell? I don't have experience with doing this - and my attempt earlier today to solve this problem didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the UITableViewController programmatically sorted this problem out. Also, ensuring that null tableview cells are set up correctly when dequeing.